# Cannot import WSDL file in SOAPUI - NT authentication pop up (Error loading WSDL)

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, soapui, soap-client

I never faced similar problem before,

I tried with SOAP 4.0.1 and also with SOAP 5.1.2.
I tried it on my windows but also and on Windows Server 2008
I try to import WSDL:
NT Authentication dialog is presented:
**Specify NT Authentication Credentials**
to populate Username,Password,Domain

I am able to open the WSDL definition in Firefox:

```
http://192.168.0.242/SO/Services/ScheduleService.svc?wsdl
```

after entering username and password

but when trying to import WSDL file or when trying to import wsdl file using location URL

```
Error loading WSDL
There was something wrong with the WSDL you are trying to import

    Error loading
 [http://192.168.0.242/SO/Services/ScheduleService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: 
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Reference to undefined entity: raquo
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got same error using latest Soap UI 5.3. No hacking with configuration helped (proxy none, authenticate preemptively etc). In the end I imported WSDL from disk. Calling of operations through NTLM then worked without any problems. It seems like a bug in SoapUI when importing WSDL through NTLM in some environments.

Update: tested that enabling anonymous auth and disabling windows auth in IIS resolves the issue with import in SoapUI. So it is definitely some kind of bug in SoapUI during import through NTLM.

Comment: In my case anonymous auth was disabled and windows auth enabled. NT authentication pop up didn't came after enabling anonymous auth, I didn't disabled windows auth

Answer (score 3):

You change the proxy settings under Preferences>Proxy Setting> to none this should solve the authentication issue which you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open this WSDL with any XML validator and see if it passes thru. The error message say

```
Reference to undefined entity: raquo
```

so you need to be sure that this entity is presented in your WSDL or imported schemas.

If your WSDL is 100% correct and "raquo" is there then I can only suggest you to download WSDL to local file with all schemas, change `schemaLocation` to local relative paths and try importing this local file.

Comment: Hi, I chekdd with XML Tools in Notepad++ and validation is success. If I try to find "raquo" in wsdl file I cannot find anything. Can you please help me what to do? When importing WSDL file it can only import WSDL file I did not downlaoed any XSD file, this is original WSDL file from the server which is I suppose in correct format. But when importing wsdl file in SOAP it does not asks for any XSD. What is my next step? I can only import WSDL file which I downloaded from the server

Comment: WSDL usually have imports, which lead to external schemas (XSDs). I usually have problems with WSDL import when SOAP-UI cannot find the referenced schemas in provided schemaLocation address; this cause that some elements or types are missing of course. You do not need to import and XSD - they should import automatically during WSDL import. Please check if your WSDL have  imports and if it does - check if the schema is available by schemaLocation address.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem here, with a WSDL that works on a different system.
It was the proxy setting that was causing the problem,
and as I don't need the proxy server, just disabling it through the browser menu solved it for me.

Comment: [This literally made my day. I tried many things that i was thinking were causing the issue. Than i simply just tried to disable proxy (red is disabled) and magically everything worked. I had same error loading the wsdl .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtC1v.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Providing proxy credentials solved the issue for me.

Comment: where did you put credentials? what authentication method did you set Basic, Windows or Anonymous?

Comment: I have applied the steps in this link; http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/authenticating-soap-requests.html

Comment: But this is set after WSDL is loaded if I am not mistaken. Unfortunately my issue is during the WSDL import and I am not able to set those settings that you provided because I am not able to import wsdl file

Comment: No. In my case, I could not load WSDL because of the authentication. After I set requierd parameters, it is loaded without any problem.

Answer (score -1):

I too faced this issue. Solution - Connect to Open Network (Non office network) and sent the Proxy setting in SOAPUI as None.