# Importing WSDL to soapUI from HTTP server using Integrated Windows Authentication

Tags: soapui, windows-authentication, ntlm, spnego

I am trying to import a WSDL (referencing a number of XSDs) to soapUI 5.0.0 (Build Date: 20140409-1012) from an intranet HTTP server requiring Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA, also referred to as NTLM and SPNEGO).

Using web browsers and other windows applications (such as Altova XMLSpy) it works opening the WSDL.

However, when using soapUI, I get a question on user name, password and domain. When I provide these details I get an error message and the console reads:

```
15:59:04,474 INFO  [WsdlLoader] xxx.yyy.com:443 requires Windows authentication org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected element: TAG_END
```

I found [this site](http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/spnego/kerberos-authentication.html) on the subject, but I am not sure on whether it applies also to WSDL imports.

Is it supported to import in this way? How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you marked, since you are using SoapUI 5.0 you could perfectly use the steps detailed on the site you [provided](http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/spnego/kerberos-authentication.html), it applies to WSDL imports.

If you want to try a workaround used in the times when SoapUI doesn't supportes NLTM, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914899/testing-webservice-with-soapui-windows-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

Related issue with [importing WSDL through NTLM in SoapUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860655/cannot-import-wsdl-file-in-soapui-nt-authentication-pop-up-error-loading-wsdl/). There I provided my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43231318/981396) stating there is very probably a bug in SoapUI when importing through NTLM in some environments. The best workaround is to download the WSDL (and its references) and import it from disk. Calling of operations through NTLM works in SoapUI as expected.